# QAndroidJNI callMethod error

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, android-ndk

I have the following java functions that open an USB port in accessory mode.

```
public int openAccessory() throws Exception { /* Open stuff */ }
public int closeAccessory() throws IOException { /* Close stuff */ }
```

I'm calling these functions from C++ instantiating a QAndroidJniObject called JavaObject, and doing the following calls:

```
int AOAConnection::Open() {
    JNIEnvironmentAttacher jea(&this->JNIE);
    return JavaObject.callMethod<jint>("openAccessory");
}

int AOAConnection::Close() {
    JNIEnvironmentAttacher jea(&this->JNIE);
    return JavaObject.callMethod<jint>("closeAccessory", "(V)I");
}
```

So this code is working fine and dandy,the thing is if I change the first C++ call to (which I was doing previously):

```
return JavaObject.callMethod<jint>("openAccessory", "(V)I");
```

My program burns and crashes hard. Why is this? Am I depending on some kind of twisted UB for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int AOAConnection::Close () {
    JNIEnvironmentAttacher jea(&this->JNIE);
    return JavaObject.callMethod<jint>("closeAccessory", "(V)I");
}
```

> So this code is working fine

You were just lucky it did: as `closeAccessory` takes no paramater but you mentioned it does get one (`(V)I`) and did not specify it anyway. So yes, I bet you're getting some undefined behaviour here and then it's not quite surprising (even if probably hard to explain why in detail) that if you repeat the same mistake with a different function call you get a crash...